# Converting an integer to numeric using as

Tags: r

I was trying to coerce an integer to numeric using `as` and found the following:

```
str(as(1L, "numeric"))
# int 1

str(as.numeric(1L))
# num 1

str(as(1L, "double"))
# num 1
```

I am expecting the first to be a numeric type as well. Why does it not return a numeric vector? Do I need `match.fun("as.numeric")` instead?

As there are many questions on `as.numeric`, I am unable to find a dupe for this.But if there is, I am very happy to close the question.

Using R-3.6.1 Win x64

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?double`

> The potential confusion is that R has used mode "numeric" to mean
>   ‘double or integer’

From `?numeric`

> `as.numeric` is a generic function, but `S3` methods must be written for
>   `as.double`. It is identical to `as.double`.

Basically, nothing's changed when you do `as(1L, "numeric")` because `1L` is already `numeric`.

For whatever reason, `as.numeric` seems to be identical to `as.double`.

Things may be different for `S4`.

Comment: `str(1L)` is integer. Do you mean 1L is stored as numeric under the hood?

Comment: Also worth noting : `is.numeric(1L)` and `is.integer(1L)` both return `TRUE`.

Comment: @chinsoon12, It seems like R considers both integer and double to be 'numeric'. The confusing part is `as.numeric` which seems to be synonymous to `as.double`

Comment: okok got it. both `as.numeric` and `as.double` share the same R code. `as(1L, typeof(1))` will work.